# iPhone 6 simulator, hide keyboard issue

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios8, iphone-6

Does the iPhone 6 have some new way (off-screen/hard button) to reopen a hidden soft keyboard?  I don't have a physical device to test with, but I'm seeing something new in the iPhone 6 simulator that I don't see in iPad or iPhone 5.

The iPhone 6, in landscape view, now has a "hide keyboard" button, like only iPad has had before.  Here are the different behaviors I'm seeing, and I'm hoping it is not a new issue I need to design my apps around.

Initial steps are the same in iPad and iPhone 6 simulators (and tested on physical iPad and works same as simulator):

1. Switch to landscape orientation
2. Open Calendar app (probably other apps too, but wanted to give example using native app, it happens in my app also which is why I care)
3. Tap + to add a new event
4. Tap in a text field
5. Tap the "hide keyboard" button in bottom-right corner
6. Tap to another text field

On physical iPad and iPad simulator the keyboard reopens at this point.  With iPhone 6 simulator, the keyboard doesn't reopen.

I've tried some different combinations of resignFirstResponder and becomeFirstResponder in my app to try to get it to reappear, but nothing is working.  Because the Calendar app also has this issue I'm hoping it isn't actually an issue, and there is a way for the user to reopen the keyboard manually if they want?  In the simulator I can use "toggle software keyboard" and it reopens, but not sure if the physical device has something that lets the user reopen the keyboard?

If I switch to another app, or the home screen, after that the keyboard does start working as expected again (tap a text field and it opens).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try unchecking Hardware => Keyboard => Connect Hardware Keyboard.

Comment: Haven't had time to test this yet but based on the number of up-votes I'm going to assume it is a good answer.  Will be back to this project in a few days, so this WILL really help then.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Try these keys to open soft keyboard =>  `Command + K`

Comment: acutally it is Shift + Command + K and mentioned in the Simulator Menu but for me a good hint to look at this.

Comment: you are right, I used the other one. sorry, upvoted you already.